# Handling new line/ line breaks with the use of Jsoup

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jsoup, jspx

While parsing an Jspx file through Jsoup I noticed that when new line is encountered and if the closing html tag is present then jsoup will be treating the content as outside of the tag. Also, I dont want the content to be present in the output which is in between .

For Example:-

My jspx file:-

```
<div xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags"
xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:util="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/util" 
xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page">

<div> I only require this text </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        var myVar= '${myVar}',
        var myVar1= '${myVar1}',
        var myVar2= '${myVar2}',
        var myVar3= '${myVar3}',
        var myVar4= '${myVar4}';
</script>
```

In java code :-

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(s);
String text = doc.body().text();
```

Now, when I run this code:-

Actual O/P:-

```
xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:util="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/util" 
xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page">

I only require this text

var myVar= '${myVar}',
var myVar1= '${myVar1}',
var myVar2= '${myVar2}',
var myVar3= '${myVar3}',
var myVar4= '${myVar4}';
```

And Expected is:-

```
I only require this text
```

The same thing happens when the comments is added and after few lines I am closing the comments then it shows ("-->") in the output as well.

I may be doing something wrong or may not be aware of complete scope of Jsoup. Can anyone help me with this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With the given input, and your commands, JSoup is actually doing the right thing.

Let's break it down:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(s);
```

When presented with an arbitrary String to parse, JSoup will wrap it in `<html>` and `<body>` tags to make the resulting `Document` somewhat valid.

```
String text = doc.body().text();
```

Now you're asking for [**all the text** of the document's `body` and all its children](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#text%28%29). So JSoup happily gives you exactly that - stripping out tags it recognizes and leaving you with more than you wanted.

The real power of JSoup comes with the [`select()` method on `Elements`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#select%28java.lang.String%29), so lets use it to narrow down to the `div` of interest:

```
String text = doc.body().select("div div").text();
```

If you're not familiar with CSS and/or JQuery, this is simply selecting ONLY elements that are a `div` inside another `div` - which should pick out your target text nicely.

Note that if you want to be really safe, you would ideally identify the div of interest (i.e. `<div id="mydiv">I only require this text</div>`) and then also use `ownText` in preference to `text`:

```
String text = doc.body().select("div#mydiv").ownText();
```

[`ownText()` only gets the immediate text of *this* element](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#ownText%28%29), so if someone adds a child element to `#mydiv` it won't break anything/

Comment: Well, I don't want tag specific (i.e. in this case <div>). There can be many other tags like <c:if>, <p> etc...

The power of Jsoup is its generic nature which is the most useful feature. But where it has short come is that when it encounters new line character.